# Proving The Maxima Of Function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose $f$ is a real - valued differentiable function defined on $[1, ∞)$ with $f(1)=1$. Suppose, $f$ satisfies $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+f^2(x)}.$$Prove that $f(x)\leq 1+\frac{π}{4}$ for all $x\geq 1$.

Answer (score 2):

$f'(x)>0$ implies that $f(x)\ge 1$ for $x\geq 1$. The identity in the problem shows that $f'$ is continuous. By fundamental theorem of calculus, for $x\geq 1$,
$$f(x)-f(1)=\int_1^x f'(t)\,dt\leq\int_1^x\frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt\leq\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{4}.$$
Hence $f(x)\leq f(1)+\frac{\pi}{4}=1+\frac{\pi}{4}$ for $x\geq 1$.

Comment: I want to know that in this problem $f'(x)$ is defined everywhere and is never equal to $0$ and $1+\frac{π}{4}$ is the Maxima of $f$ but how is this possible

Comment: @user679770 The problem never said that $1+\frac{\pi}4$ is the maxima of $f$. The problem can only imply that the maxima of $f$ is no greater than $1+\frac{\pi}4$. As you pointed out, actually, $f$ cannot reach $1+\frac{\pi}4$.

Comment: But in your proof you have used the sign $\leq$ instead of $<$

Comment: @user679770 $\leq$ doesn't mean the equality holds.  For example, we can say both "$2\leq3$" and "$2<3$".